# I need a regex that will return false if my value contains any letters

Tags: javascript

I need a **regex** that will return false if valueA contains any letters.
I need letters rejected basically

**Examples**:

1)  test1 => reject
2)  test => reject
3)  123 = > accept

```
            this.validateLetters = (valueA): boolean => {
                const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
                return regex.test(valueA);
            };
```

I'm using javascript

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "letters"?  If you're dealing with the realm of unicode characters, you may find you run into problems with JS based regexes.

Comment: do you want it to _reject letters_ or _accept numbers_?

Comment: accept numbers and reject letters

Comment: This will be from a basic input text field

Comment: So...you want it to just accept numbers then. By definition letters will be rejected.

Comment: This should do it. `/^[0-9]$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex used is `/^[0-9]+$/`

You should replace `+` by `*` if an empty string is acceptable

```js
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test("10.22")); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test(10.22)); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('')); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('test1')); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('test')); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('123')); 
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('{}'));
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('//'));
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/.test('()'));
```

Comment: i did this: console.log(/^[0-9]*$/.test(''));  and it said it contained letters

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you just want to accept numbers or?

```
const regex = /([0-9])/g;
regex.test("123"); //true
regex.test("123a"); //false
```

What you can also do is except every "letter":

```
const regex = /([^A-Za-z])/g;
```

But be careful using this! It also recognizes whitespaces and other symbols.

Or are you talking about unicode chars? That could be a little bit tricky with javascript.

Comment: @bashOne I want to check if theres any letter only from a string

Comment: @AngularM so you want to accept symbols too? So just letters are the condition?

Answer (score 0):

`/[^a-zA-Z]/g`

`^` Except operator.
`g` Global operator.

This regex will not match any letters from A-Z and a-z.

It will match numbers and other symbols.

Comment: `123!"£$%^&*()_+?@:~><¬[]{}\| ;'#` is also valid, yet OP wanted numbers only

Comment: Presumably. To be honest, I'm really confused what OP wants - he says he wants to reject letters but also says he wants numbers (in which case the letter rejection is irrelevant). He also hasn't really specified if anything else is valid but neither has he asked for anything else to be valid.

Comment: Then maybe you should ask again, i think these regexes solves your current explained problem.